# Front Users Profile - Best Strategy

Tags: strapi

I will have two or 3 types of users on the front (Clients, Providers, and Manufacturers) and each user will have different set of features and data profile.
Which is the best strategy you imagine for creating the content types for each type of user?
In my head, I have in mind to create 3 content types related to Users and set a field for USERTYPE, and the front requests the rest of the profile on the other content type.
What do you think?
Also related to security, is it possible to set access to contents according to different user types?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's depending of you want to do and depending of your application need.

You can also create roles, one for Clients, one for Providers and one for Manufacturers. You will be able to manage who can do what.